# Save Outlook email as .elm file using add-in compose mode

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, add-in, office-addins

I am developing an outlook add-in which should allow user to save the outlook email which is in compose mode as a .eml file and save it to Google Drive/Dropbox before sending.
I was able to get the message body, cc, to, subject etc but unable to get the attachment.
Is there a way I can get all the details of the Item including attachment using ItemId  and save it as .elm file?

In compose mode on clicking send button I managed to get ItemId and  using it the rest of the message data.

```
       Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function (result) {      
    itemId = result.value;
    var soapToGetItemData = getItemDataRequest(result.value);       
    Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(soapToGetItemData, function (asyncResult) {           
        if (asyncResult.error != null) {
            updateAndComplete("EWS Status: " + asyncResult.error.message);
            return;
        }
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(asyncResult.value, "text/xml");           
        var values = doc.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName("t:ItemId");          
        var ItemId = values[0].attributes['Id'].value;            
        var changeKey = values[0].attributes['ChangeKey'].value;  
        var soapToSendItem = getItemRequest(ItemId, changeKey);           
        Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(soapToSendItem, function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.error != null) {
                statusUpdate("EWS Status: " + asyncResult.error.message);
                return;
            }
            console.log('fulldata');
            console.log(asyncResult);

        });
    });  
});
```

asyncResult has the full data of composed message.

using makeEwsRequestAsync how can I save this mail as .eml in hard disk?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko updated the question.Please check